# Join multiple left values with one right value

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

In Codeigniter I am tryign to join two tables with one to many relation. I want to get one result from my table `housetype` and all of its values/members from other table `housetype_member`:

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('housetype_member', 'housetype_member.housetype_id = housetype.PkId', 'left');
    $result = $this->db->get_where('housetype', array('PkId' => $id));

    return $result->result();
```

So far I get such result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[28]
      public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
      public 'image' => string '1449063250.jpg' (length=14)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
      public 'image' => string '1449063288.gif' (length=14)
```

First two object values (PkID, Name) are from the first table and the last one (image) is from the second left table. Everything is good but I get array with two elements, when I only need one `housetype` object.

Is there a way to write above code so that my returned object would look like this:

```
object(stdClass)[28]
  public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
  public 'image' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1449063250.jpg' (length=14)
      1 => string '1449063288.gif' (length=14)
```

I need one result from first table and to it I want to join all of its members from the second table.

Can it be done with Codeigniters active record?

Comment: You can achieve this with [MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model).

Comment: @Tpojka I am already using extended model by Bonfire extension and I don't want to switch it so late in the project. MY_Model has interesting features though

Answer (score 1):

As far as your second table has multi records with that primary key, it is better if you don't use joins at all.
You can simply get that with two selects.

```
$this->db->select('PkID, name');
$this->db->where('PkId', $id);
$houseTypes = $this->db->get('housetype')->result();
foreach($houseTypes as $houseType){
    $this->db->select('image');
    $this->db->where('housetype_id', $houseType->PKId);
    $houseType->image = $this->db->get('housetype_member')->result();
}
return $houseTypes;
```

Comment: Putting DB query action in foreach loop is big no no.